# Creating a CMD Context menu to copy filepath

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, cmd.exe, context-menu

I created a context menu in the registry

HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT > * > shell > copy > commmand > `cmd /c dir  "%1" /b /a:-d /o:n | clip`

What this does is copies the file name when I right click on a file, yet I want to add it so it will copy some text before the file name.

so it would be like `db.yetteh.co.uk/%1` with `%1` being the filename.

```
cmd /c echo db.yetteh.co.uk & dir  "%1" /b /a:-d /o:n | clip
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

#### It would be like `db.yetteh.co.uk/%1` with `%1` being the filename.

Use the following command line:

```
cmd /c "<nul (set/p _v=db.yetteh.co.uk/) & dir "%1" /b /a:-d /o:n" | clip
```

**Batch file (example.cmd):**

```
cmd /c "<nul (set/p _v=db.yetteh.co.uk/) & dir "%1" /b /a:-d /o:n" | clip
```

Note:

- `<nul (set/p _v=db.yetteh.co.uk/)` is a trick to "echo" text without a trailing `<cr><lf>`

**Usage**:

```
F:\test>example test.cmd

F:\test>cmd /c "<nul (set/p _v=db.yetteh.co.uk/) & dir "test.cmd" /b /a:-d /o:n"   | clip

F:\test>
```

**Clipboard contents**:

```
db.yetteh.co.uk/test.cmd
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [dir](http://ss64.com/nt/dir.html) - Display a list of files and subfolders.
- [echo](http://ss64.com/nt/echo.html) - Display messages on screen, turn command-echoing on or off.
- [set](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) - Display, set, or remove CMD environment variables. Changes made with SET will remain only for the duration of the current CMD session.